# Unexpected { & T-Strings

Tags: php

Ok so I need this code to check and see if the users have either session. They dont have to have both that would be odd since one is an admin and one is for users. But im getting an error thats says unexpected { but i dont know why. When i remove the curly brackets i get unexpected T_STRING error. Im very new to isset but it was recomended i use this rather that session_is_registered. Please help me!

```
<?php session_start(); 
include('../../phpconfig/connect.php'); 
if ( (!isset($_SESSION['premiersounds_username']) || (!isset($_SESSION['user']) ) {header("location:http://psdjs.co/login%20system/index.php?error=PLEASE LOGIN TO VIEW EVENTS!");} ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You unbalanced parentheses in your code.

This should work:

```
<?php
session_start(); 
include('../../phpconfig/connect.php'); 
if (!isset($_SESSION['premiersounds_username']) || !isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    header("location:http://psdjs.co/login%20system/index.php?error=PLEASE LOGIN TO VIEW EVENTS!");
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two extra `(`, change

```
if ( (!isset($_SESSION['premiersounds_username']) || (!isset($_SESSION['user']) )
```

to

```
if ( !isset($_SESSION['premiersounds_username']) || !isset($_SESSION['user']) )
```